# Add "previous" & "next" buttons in master/detail flow template

Tags: android, eclipse

I am creating an application using the master/detail flow template in android...by default it shows the data in a 2-pane activity in tablets, and single-pane with navigation in handsets....i want to add "previous" and "next" buttons in the detail activity (for handsets) so that navigation becomes easier, (its quite cumbersome to go back to the listActivity each time .....)...but im not able to do that....please help :(. Here's the main code of ItemDetailActivity

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID,
                getIntent().getStringExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID));
        ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
```